# Ansible - using delegate_to run tasks on the same remote machine as a different user

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook to execute a few tasks on a remote node. The requirement is that I have to execute some of those tasks as one user (say foo-user) and other tasks as a different user (say bar-user). So I defined **two different entries (node-foo & node-bar) in  the inventories hosts file** for the same remote node IP and then I defined **hosts:node-foo** at the playbook level.  For those tasks, which I would like to execute as bar-user I used **delegate_to: node-bar** option.

During the playbook execution, It is getting failed at the first task with **delegate_to**.  I understand that it is unable to access the remote tmp directory created by the first user (foo-user) as the second user (bar-user) on remote node and hence task execution is getting failed.

Is there any way on how to solve this without giving 777 persmissions to the remote tmp directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [*remote_user*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/connection_details.html#setting-a-remote-user) instead of *delegate_to*. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: test_01

  tasks:

    - command: whoami
      register: out
      remote_user: alice
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout

    - command: whoami
      register: out
      remote_user: bob
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  out.stdout: alice
  out.stdout: bob
```

By default, the *remote_user* creates the [*remote_tmp*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/sh_shell.html#parameter-remote_tmp) directory *~/.ansible/tmp*

```bash
shell> ssh alice@test_01 ls -la /home/alice/.ansible/ | grep tmp
drwx------  6 alice  alice   6 Nov 15 06:34 tmp
```

```bash
shell> ssh bob@test_01 ls -la /home/bob/.ansible/ | grep tmp
drwx------  6 bob  bob   6 Nov 15 06:34 tmp
```

---

Q:  ***"It is required to specify ansible become password for the users."***

A: If you for whatever reason decide not to use the passwordless [escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html)

```bash
shell> sudo cat /usr/local/etc/sudoers
  ...
alice ALL=(ALL) ALL
bob ALL=(ALL) ALL
  ...
```

and there are more remote users who should escalate the privileges, put the passwords into the *vars*. There are more options:

- For example, use a file in *group_vars_all* (and encrypt it)

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/ansible_become_pass.yml 
abp:
  alice: alice
  bob: bob
```

Use the passwords in the tasks. For example,

```yaml
    - command: whoami
      become: true
      register: out
      remote_user: alice
      vars:
        ansible_become_pass: "{{ abp.alice }}"
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout

    - command: whoami
      become: true
      register: out
      remote_user: bob
      vars:
        ansible_become_pass: "{{ abp.bob }}"
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [command] **************
changed: [test_01]

TASK [debug] ****************
ok: [test_01] => 
  out.stdout: root

TASK [command] **************
changed: [test_01]

TASK [debug] ****************
ok: [test_01] => 
  out.stdout: root
```

---

- Optionally, put the passwords into single files (and encrypt them)

```bash
shell> cat vault/abp_alice.yml
alice
shell> cat vault/abp_bob.yml
bob
```

Then, the below tasks

```yaml
    - command: whoami
      become: true
      register: out
      remote_user: alice
      vars:
        ansible_become_pass: "{{ lookup('file', 'vault/abp_alice.yml') }}"
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout

    - command: whoami
      become: true
      register: out
      remote_user: bob
      vars:
        ansible_become_pass: "{{ lookup('file', 'vault/abp_bob.yml') }}"
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

work as expected and give

```yaml
TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [test_01]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  out.stdout: root

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [test_01]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  out.stdout: root
```

- If the passwords vary among the remote hosts use a dictionary

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/ansible_become_pass.yml 
abp:
  test_01:
    alice: alice_01
    bob: bob_01
  test_02:
    alice: alice_02
    bob: bob_02
```

and use it in the tasks

```yaml
    - command: whoami
      become: true
      register: out
      remote_user: alice
      vars:
        ansible_become_pass: "{{ abp[inventory_hostname]['alice'] }}"
```

Note: You can use both keyword [remote_user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords) and variable [ansible_user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#parameter-remote_user) to configure "User name with which to login to the remote server". To specify [passwords for enable mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#passwords-for-enable-mode) there are only two options:

- providing the **--ask-become-pass** command line option
- setting the **ansible_become_password** connection variable

Take a look at the parameter [become_pass](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/become/runas.py#L46) of the *become* plugin

```yaml
        become_pass:
            description: password
            ini:
              - section: runas_become_plugin
                key: password
            vars:
              - name: ansible_become_password
              - name: ansible_become_pass
              - name: ansible_runas_pass
            env:
              - name: ANSIBLE_BECOME_PASS
              - name: ANSIBLE_RUNAS_PASS
```

You can see three aliases for the same variable:

- ansible_become_password
- ansible_become_pass
- ansible_runas_pass

Comment: Could you please let me know the better way to define the hosts file in this case?  
 Please note that It is also required to specify ansible become password for the users to execute a few tasks

Comment: It's up to you how you define hosts. Put the passwords into the vars. I added an example. Why is it important that more users escalate to root? Why isn't just one sufficient?

Comment: Please help me to understand how ansible_user is different from remote_user in this scenario. I have already specified ansible_user in my inventory host file and  ansible become password as suggested by you.  But, it did not work for me.
I also followed the link you have shared to understand this. But, I did not get it completely.

Comment: See the parameter [remote_user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#parameter-remote_user) of the ssh connection. Both *remote_user* and *ansible_user* deliver the "User name with which to login to the remote server". The only difference is that *remote_user* is a parameter also available as a [keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html) and [configuration](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-remote-user), but *ansible_user* is variable.

Comment: You've specified *ansible_user* in your inventory host file but this didn't work for you. Very probably you override the variable(s). See [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence). Display what you got: ``- debug: var=ansible_user``